# How can I add a full screen maskview on uiviewcontroller with alpha

Tags: ios, objective-c

Below is my code snippet

```
_maskView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 667)];
_maskView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
_maskView.alpha = 0.5;

UIButton *disappare = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 200, 120, 44)];
disappare.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
disappare.alpha = 1.0;
[disappare setTitle:@"消失" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[disappare addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissMaskView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_maskView addSubview:disappare];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:_maskView];
```

I add maskView to navigationController.view, but when I set alpha on maskview, it affects maskview.subviews like [image] ,

How can I set maskview.alpha not effect disappeare button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set `alpha` of a view, it will apply to its subView's also. Instead you can use `alpha` for the background color

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5];
```

I'm not sure about the color code, anyway `alpha` is the key.